# Tem como referenciar um enum dentro dele mesmo em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

Gostaria de usar uma constante que criei em um enum como um atributo de outra, por exemplo:

```
from enum import Enum


class Jokenpo(Enum):
    PEDRA = ('Rock', [Jokenpo.PAPEL], [Jokenpo.TESOURA])
    PAPEL = ('Paper', [Jokenpo.TESOURA], [Jokenpo.PEDRA])
    TESOURA = ('Scissors', [Jokenpo.PEDRA], [Jokenpo.PAPEL])


    def __init__(self, nome, fraco, forte):
        self.nome = nome
        self.fraco = fraco
        self.forte = forte
```

Em um jogo de pedra-papel-tesoura, para especificar que pedra perde para papel mas vence tesoura posso fazer algo parecido com isso. Provavelmente meu enum possui alguns erros, sou iniciante, mas tem como usar uma constante dentro de outra?

Comment: Soa como [o problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/o-que-%c3%a9-o-problema-xy). Eu analiso que você quer implementar a lógica do jogo, em vez de realmente ter essa dúvida sobre enums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem, mas não da maneira que você está fazendo, embora não seja realmente um problema criar um enumerável a partir de tuplas, mas a lógica, em si, ficou bastante estranha.

Tendo em mente que cada valor do `Enum` será uma instância do próprio `Enum`, você pode definir uma propriedade que retorna a fraqueza e força de cada item. Por exemplo:

```
from enum import Enum

class Jokenpo(Enum):
    PEDRA = 1
    PAPEL = 2
    TESOURA = 3

    @property
    def weakness(self):
        if self == self.PEDRA:
            return self.PAPEL
        elif self == self.PAPEL:
            return self.TESOURA
        else:
            return self.PEDRA

print(Jokenpo.PEDRA.weakness)  # Jokenpo.PAPEL
print(Jokenpo.PAPEL.weakness)  # Jokenpo.TESOURA
print(Jokenpo.TESOURA.weakness)  # Jokenpo.PEDRA
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/KlutzySuperClick) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/OYJqD0) | [GitHub GIST](https://gist.github.com/d64cbb6f4b37e49cf78b20ae1f846637)</sup>